# How to link the carrier to the tracking number in the email template

Tags: magento2.4.3

Currently, the following code is used to display the tracking number.

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_track" shipment_id=$shipment_id order_id=$order_id}}
```

Is it possible to embed the tracking number within a specific URL using the HTML a tag above?